# How to capture SATA traffic under Linux?

Tags: wireshark, sata

Using `usbmon` it's possible to capture USB traffic in Wireshark.

I want to do the same for SATA.

Is it possible?

If it is not possible in Wireshark directly it would be nice to later open the capture in Wireshark.

Comment: As Wireshark is a network traffic analysis tool and no SATA network interfaces exist - at least to my knowledge - I'm pretty certain this is not doable. I'm not aware of any purely SW-based solution for this at all, I've only seen paid solutions that require some dedicated HW like Teledyne's Sierra -devices.

Comment: @Peregrino69 A HW based solution does not make sense because the kernel knows what goes out and in. Also as already said Wireshark can capture USB traffic too. As you see Wireshark is not limited to network traffic.